# How to display contact us form echo result

Tags: php, html

code is working and I'm getting when I try to send mail from website contact us form but when I click Send button on website it redirects me and getting echo result that message have successfully sent but I want to display that echo in same page.

PHP code:

```
 <?php 
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

mail("info@info.info", "From info.info", $message, "From: $email\r\n");

if(isset($_POST['btn-send']))
echo "Thank you for your message"; ?>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="second_third">
  <h6 class="title" style="padding-left: 45px;">Contact Us</h6>
  <ul class="nospace linklist">
   <form class="form1" method="post" action="send.php">
    Mail<br />
    <input type="email" id="input-email" class="input1" name="email">
    <br />
    Message
   <textarea name="message" class="textarea1" id="input-message"></textarea>
  <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" id="input-submit" class="input1" name="btn-send">
  </form>
```

What I have to add or how to do it ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your php code also on send.php? Also what is the page the form is on? 
Right now, your form is posting to send.php, what is on send.php? As noted, if all this code is on the same page then use the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] method to post to the same page, else you can redirect back to your form page with a header redirect sending a url variable to validate the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it'll run even if you don't submit the form, assuming send.php contains the HTML form as well. Do this style thing:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['btn-send'])){
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

mail("info@info.info", "From info.info", $message, "From: $email\r\n");
echo "Thank you for your message";
}

 ?>
<form class="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Comment: So I don't need send.php file and I have to write this code in HTML file?

Comment: Don't HAVE to, but for something this simple I would. You could leave it as is and just take this if(isset($_POST['btn-send'])){ echo "Thank you for your message"; } and put it in the top of your HTML form as well, leaving the action on the form as send.php like previously.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a small jquery code to do an ajax call to the php code. It will not reload the page, rather display an alert or a message box with your message on the same page. Please find the below code

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div class="second_third">
  <h6 class="title" style="padding-left: 45px;">Contact Us</h6>
  <ul class="nospace linklist">
   <form class="form1" >
    Mail<br />
    <input type="email" id="input-email" class="input1" name="email">
    <br />
    Message
   <textarea name="message" class="textarea1" id="input-message"></textarea>
  <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" id="input-submit" class="input1" name="btn-send" onclick="mail();">
  </form>
  </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function mail(){
    var email=$('#input-email').val();
    var message=$('#input-message').val();
    $.ajax({
       url:'mail.php',
       method:'post',
       data:{email:email, message:message},
       success:function(data){
          alert(data);
      }
     })
   }
  </script>
  </body>
```

**Mail.php**

```
<?php 
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];

mail("info@info.info", "From info.info", $message, "From: $email\r\n");
echo "Thank you for your message"; ?>
```

Comment: in this case if isset isn't necessary ?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['btn-send']))` is used to check if any value is set to the button, or simple words, if it is clicked. We are using a `onclick="mail();"` in the submit button itself, so the function will run when the button will be clicked.

Comment: So why I need <form class="form1" method="post" action="send.php"> send.php here?

Comment: Ops, My Fault!, You need to remove the entire form tag too! or the action and post part too! I'll edit it.

Comment: It works fine, when I click I'm getting mail but echo won't display anywhere :(

Comment: try adding ` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`  before the script at the bottom of page, (if you have not imported teh jquery anywhere else on the same page). The echo message will be shown as an alert.!

Comment: http://website.com/index.php?email=asdsa%40gmail.com&message=asdasd&btn-send=Send 
when I click send button tab link turns like this, I added that script which you wrote me googleapis but still nothing changed